# caffeine wingpanel on github

Tags: wingpanel

I compiled the app in the github..

https://github.com/PlugaruT/wingpanel-caffeine

It does not seem to work.. or at least the icon does not change.. and is a generic icon for eos.

I hope I did not compile and install a virus because it was called ninja.
Does anyone know about this.  How to remove it too.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ninja` is not a virus, it is a build system like `make` or `cmake`.

However, you have built and installed an indicator that is not finished or ready for use. Github is not an application store, and you should not install things off there unless you understand what you are doing and trust the developer. In fact, you should not run any commands you find anywhere on the internet without understanding what they do first.

To uninstall it, run the following from the same directory that you ran the commands to install the indicator:

```
sudo ninja uninstall
```

This instructs `ninja`, the tool you used to install the indicator to remove any files it installed when you ran `sudo ninja install`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did look through the code first.. but not all of it.  It seems to be a shame that the eOS team has removed indicator apps but there are no samples on how to do things with some of the most popular indicator apps

Comment: The caffeine indicator you installed is not associated with elementary OS. Within the github repository for wingpanel, there is a sample indicator that gives an example on how to write new indicators for elementary: https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel/tree/master/sample

Comment: Are there any elementary compliant indicators.?  Why wouldn't a proper sample show how to do it on a real indicator ?  And why not have a shell wrapper  for migration.?